# Cut out shape of another shape in CSS - cross-browser compatibility

Tags: html, css

I have white and red, full circles, absolutely positioned divs. Is there a way that I can cut out all white circles to be transparent with CSS and to be cross-browser compatible? Looking for the most "primitive" way.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: take a look at radial-gradient maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use border-radius for that.

Check this example:

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  width: 490px;
  height: 490px;
  position: relative;
  background: black url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/recycled_texture_background_by_sandeep_m-d6aeau9_PZ9chud.jpg) no-repeat -500px -500px;
}
.r1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 400px;
  border: 30px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.r2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 300px;
  border: 30px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}
.r3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 30px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="r1"></div>
  <div class="r2"></div>
  <div class="r3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! As simple as it gets.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

you may take a look at radial gradient:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle   /* a circle*/
    closest-side at 50% 50%   /* set as closed as possible to center*/,
    transparent 0 /* from center */,
    /* to */transparent 50px, 
    /* from */red 50px, 
    /* to */red 60px,
    /*from */transparent 60px, 
    /* to */transparent 70px,
    /* from */red 70px, 
    /* to */red 80px,
    /* from */transparent 80px,
    /* to */ transparent 100px,
    /* from */ red 100px,
    /* to */ red 120px,
    /* from */ transparent 120px
    /* and so or till end */), 
    /* bg image to show transparency */     url(http://lorempixel.com/150/150);
}
```

keep repeating the pattern as much as needed. you can also use `calc()` [example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BQoBzV) to mix percentage and pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG as well.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
svg {
  flex: 1;
  background: url(http://fillmurray.com/638/220) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40" stroke="#F44336" stroke-width="8" fill="none" />
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="60" stroke="#F44336" stroke-width="6" fill="none" />
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="80" stroke="#F44336" stroke-width="10" fill="none" />
</svg>
```